# Dynamically / automatically label all points with point value (tikzpicture graf / plot)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Anyway to dynamically / automatically label all points with point value (tikzpicture graf / plot)?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    ,width=15cm
    ,xlabel={Gjennomsnittlig lengde verdi for 10 nivåer}
    ,ylabel=Lengde verdi
    ,xtick=data,
   %,xtick={0,1,...,3}
    ,xticklabels={Nivå 1,Nivå 2,Nivå 3,Nivå 4,Nivå 5,Nivå 6,Nivå 7,Nivå 8,Nivå 9,Nivå 10}
    ]

    \addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates
    { (0,62.37)(1,64.77)(2,67.39)(3,70.18)(4,73.33)(5,76.64)(6,80.43)(7,84.40)(8,89.03)(9,94.29)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `nodes near coords`?

Comment: yes but i would have to do it for each cord, was hoping there was a less time consuming way, as this is only one of many plots im doing.

Comment: @marmot i misunderstood your comment, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` can understand (some) patterns if supplied appropriately. Here you can use

```
xticklabels={Nivå 1,Nivå ...,Nivå 10}
```

and for the labels `nodes near coords` uses automatically point values by default

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    ,width=15cm
    ,xlabel={Gjennomsnittlig lengde verdi for 10 nivåer}
    ,ylabel=Lengde verdi
    ,xtick=data,
   %,xtick={0,1,...,3}
    ,xticklabels={Nivå 1,Nivå ...,Nivå 10},
nodes near coords
    ]
    \addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates
    { (0,62.37)(1,64.77)(2,67.39)(3,70.18)(4,73.33)(5,76.64)(6,80.43)(7,84.40)(8,89.03)(9,94.29)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! :) Thanks a bunch